# How is our voice tone transmitted and received without the change of our own voice?

Tags: rf, wireless, transmitter, receiver

For example lets take mobile communication, transmitting and receiving what we speak is fine, but how does it retains different flavors of our unique voice (that is if someone who we knows speaks over phone we could easily able to identify their voice in unknown number also.) What factor is responsible for that?

If we say hello, at receiver getting hello is expected but we received the hello with their original voice.

Can anyone please explain science behind this?

Comment: The phone just reproduces the original soundwaves as closely as possible. Just like, for example, music recorded on a CD. It doesn't "interpret" the speech, it just relays the soundwaves verbatim.

Comment: No-one has yet mentioned the confounding process of speech compression, used in mobile comms to reduce the raw data rate. However that's fairly moot these days. After the initial inefficient codes produced for GSM, two routes were pursued. One halved the data rate while retaining mediocre quality, the other improved the quality. The network operators wanted to push the former, more connections for the same bandwidth = more profit. But it was difficult to sell, customers wanted the better quality. So - why do mobile comms have clearly recognizable speech? Because customers demand it.

Comment: Is your real question how the **human body** (ear and brain) distinguishes voices? This isn't an EE question. The electronics aim only to reproduce at one place the sound pressure waves generated in another place. Maybe you want to research _timbre_, _harmonics_, etc.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because off topic

Comment: I think this question is not about how humans recognize voices, but that it assumes phones work by converting speech to text (or some other representation of phonetic information) and vice versa. As such, it would be on topic.

Answer (score 8):

- Your voice creates vibrations (sound pressure waves) in the air.
- A microphone generates an electrical signal whose voltage changes with the air pressure. The electrical signal is an "analog" of the sound signal.
- The electrical signal is transmitted to the receiver.
- The receiver uses the electrical signal to drive a loudspeaker which is the reverse of the microphone. It converts electrical signals into vibrations of the speaker diaphragm. The diaphragm moves the air and creates a close replica of the original soundwave that activated the microphone.

The human voice produces a complex waveform but the microphone and loudspeaker are able to convert this to an electrical signal and back to an audio signal with enough fidelity that voices can be faithfully reproduced.

Comment: "The human voice produces a complex waveform..." I got the feeling this is really the heart of the OP's question: they want to understand the concepts of pitch, timbre, harmonics, etc. But this is a physics question rather than an EE question. But good answer from the EE perspective.

Comment: @TypeIA I got the impression that OP assumed phones work by converting speech to text and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Read up on how the Fourier series works. Any wave can be made up by adding the right sinewaves of different frequencies, amplitudes, and phase shifts together. Like music instruments. A 440Hz A-note is always a 440Hz A-note no matter what instrument is playing it, but they all sound different while still sounding like that same note because the 440Hz is the strongest frequency (called the fundamental frequency) there, but there are other weaker frequencies present (called overtones) that give the note it's flavour. Otherwise it would just sound like a 440Hz pure tone.

If you record the sound waveform, you record all those frequencies. And if you filter the waveform as you record then you remove some of those frequencies which is why the voice doesn't sound like in person.

Sometimes they purposely filter those frequencies because you don't need to preserve the person's voice. Like a police radio. You only need to preserve legibility of their words to understand what is being said. Using music instruments as an example if you filtered every overtone frequency (frequency weaker than the fundamental) so only the 440Hz fundamental was remaining, then you would still know it was an A-note but you would have no idea what instrument it was coming from because there would be no overtones.

Voiced words are more complicated than music note so where as music note only requires the fundamental frequency to recognize the note, voice requires more frequencies to recognize the word. If you filter too many frequencies then the word is no longer legible.

Comment: Thanks much for your time in guiding me. Exactly!! 440HZ note sounds different in different musical instruments. And you mean voice flavores gets added in the wave and if we  filter it what may be the flavour??

Comment: @RaHuL A person's voice is a person's voice so if you filter frequencies most people would say it just sounds worse because it no longer sounds like the original. Overtones existing with the fundamental give the music note (or a voice) it's flavour. No overtones no flavour. Flavour can be good or bad.

Comment: Music instruments is a bit different than voice because there are good and bad instruments and we have an idea about what a good instrument sounds like. So filtering can make a bad instrument sound better by getting rid of unpleasant frequencies but filtering can also make a good instrument sound worse by getting rid of good frequencies.

Comment: Right got it thanks!!!@DKNguyen

Answer (score 0):

There are two things here, really. Humans are good at recognizing voices of people they know. That has to do with how humans process sound.

Second thing is sound reproduction. You talk into a microphone and an ADC captures the voltage coming from the microphone and digitizes it. The digital data are transmitted over the air to another device equipped with a DAC, amplifier and speaker. The speaker reproduces the same sound.

The sound is modified in the process due to noise, bandwidth limitations, and compression. But because humans are good at recognizing voices, the modifications to the sound don't stop us from recognizing the voice.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simplified version of other answers and comments:

Human speech is usually adequately represented for telephone quality transmission by a band of frequencies between about 300 Hz and 3400 Hz. A wider bandwidth will give better sounding speech.

In Analog system the whole band of frequencies was transmitted - in much the same way as you'd experience with a pair of wires plus a low pass and highh pass filter to limit the frequencies.

Digital systems convert the analog signals to digital and then back to analog, and may employ various "magic" to achieve this with less digital bandwidth BUT, and this is the very important point, at the receiver you again receive an analog signal that i as close to the original as possible after various cost and bandwidth constraints have been met.

The characteristics of an individuals speech are contained within the original signal. As much as possible these are preserved in the final signal.

The person is recognisable because the received signal is as close to the original signal as allowed by system constraints.

Answer (score 0):

In philosophy, for example, the inability to explain how we hear acoustic sensation as sound, or convert visual sensations into sight, is called the Hard Problem of Consciousness. On this level there is no established scientific answer to the question.

Steven W. Smith, Ph.D., an inventor and expert in digital signal processing, describes the philosophical problems in his book The Inner Light Theory of Consciousness. Here is an outline of the book:

http://www.dspguide.com/InnerLightTheory/paper.htm

And here is the online main splash page:

http://www.dspguide.com/InnerLightTheory/Main.htm

In terms of signal representation and reproduction if one has a computer, a microphone, and headphones or speaker then one can install Audacity:

https://www.audacityteam.org/

Record the voices of two or more persons. Observe the respective waveform representation. Play back the audio samples through speakers or headphones.

The computer sound card and headphones replicate the acoustic waves of the respective sound. Effects or noise can distort the sound. Audacity allows one to add noise or sound effects, to see each waveform, and hear the respective sounds. Beyond these novice experiments is the effort to learn the science of acoustic waves, the biological structures and functions, the electrical engineering principles, etc.

I have used Audacity to do basic analysis of ding-dong sound from this link:

https://orangefreesounds.com/ding-dong-doorbell-sound/

This image shows the signal representation of "ding-dong" sound:

[image]

This image is frequency analysis of the "ding dong" waveform using Audacity menu system Analyze, Plot Spectrum:

[image]

Ding frequency shown via Audacity menu system View, Zoom In:
[image]

Short waveform sample for the "dong" signal which replicates the "dong" sound via replay through the sound card:

[image]

Comment: I will Go through this book @System Theory. Thanks!!